# automatically update php output through browsers

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a live table where it's possible to edit/save realtime data like google spreadsheet and I'm looking to display the updated datas through other browsers. 
Actually this is my code:

```
  // DB AND USERS VERIFICATION....
  <table>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach($datas as $k => $v){ ?>
   <tr>
     <td contenteditable="true" id="<?php echo $v['my_id']; ?>" ></td>
     <td contenteditable="true" name="myData"> SOME TEXT </td>
   </tr>
```

Then I'm using jquery to save the contenteditable text to DB. 
My question now is how can I automatically output the updated "TD" text through different browsers without having to refresh page? 
Is there anyway to do it directly with PHP?
Thank you for your Help!!!

Comment: `AJAX` should be a start

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to do it directly with PHP?

Unfortunately not. PHP is a server side scripted language. You will need a client side scripted language to do this, and that usually means JavaScript, or other alternatives.

[Getting Started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

[Or you could use Websockets with HTML5.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)

[Or you could use Webhooks with HTTP POST.](http://www.webhook.com/docs/)

[Here is a comparison of them.](https://blog.safe.com/2014/08/websockets-ajax-webhooks-comparison/)